# Type definition of object in d3.js version 5?

Tags: typescript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to draw donut chart using d3.js v5. While calculating centroid for label positioning, I got the error in `arc.centroid(d)`.

**My Error**

```
Argument of type 'PieArcDatum<number | { valueOf(): number; }>' is not 
assignable to parameter of type 'DefaultArcObject'.ts(2345)

(parameter) d: d3.PieArcDatum<number | {
   valueOf(): number;
}>
```

**My Code**

```
   var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.67)
  .outerRadius(radius - 1);

  var text = g.selectAll("text")
  .data(pieData)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", d =>  {
    return  "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"
  })
  .attr("dy", "0.35em");
```

Kindly help me to resolve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: 99% ".data(<any>pieData)" whould save you (at compilation sage), but from your post it's hard to say what you have there

Comment: @2oppin - `error TS2345: Argument of type 'Arc<any, DefaultArcObject>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueFn<SVGPathElement, PieArcDatum<number | { valueOf(): number; }>, string | number | boolean>'.
  Types of parameters 'd' and 'datum' are incompatible.
    Type 'PieArcDatum<number | { valueOf(): number; }>' is not assignable to type 'DefaultArcObject'.
      Property 'innerRadius' is missing in type 'PieArcDatum<number | { valueOf(): number; }>'.`

This is the error I have gotten at compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

Value of the text not mapped it seems. Refactored code given below.

```
 var text = g.selectAll("text")
  .data(pieData)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", d =>  {
    return  "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"
  }).attr("dy", "0.35em").text("test");
```